# Solutions of $x(\ln x)^2=e$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The solution of $x(\ln x)^2=e$ is clearly $e$, but how can I show that it is indeed a solution conceptually (that is, **without substituting $x=e$**) and that it is unique?

Comment: *Just a remark*: In the topic of differential equations, we have this notion of variable separability. Extending that concept here, there is no direct algebraic means to put $x$ solely on any one side of the given equation.  You need calculus here to analyze the monotonic nature of $f(x) = x(\ln x)^2$ and some poetic trickery is required for the rest.

Comment: @Nick Very good remark. Unfortunately, right now I'm interested in the trickery.

Comment: [Maybe the graph could be helpful?](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%28ln+x%29%5E2+and+e)

Comment: @mathlearner: I am just as curious about it as you are.

Comment: A typo by me `^` rather than `*` which was hidden when $\ln x=1$. Ignore my previous comments

Comment: *Thinking out of the box* : Anyone well-versed in plotting functions by hand will be able to plot [$(\ln x)^2$ against $\dfrac{e}{x}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28ln+x%29%5E2+and+e%2Fx) to find the unique solution where $x \in \Bbb R\sim\{0\}$. Although, without cool geometry or some other cleverness, I don't know how he'd prove that point is $x = e$. But it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(x)=x\log^2 x$ is a continuous and increasing function on $(1,+\infty)$, as a product of two continuous, non-negative and increasing functions on the same interval. Since $g(1)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty} g(x)=+\infty$, the map between $(1,+\infty)$ and $(0,+\infty)$ given by $g$ is one-to-one.

Comment: I didn't get the last passage. Could you explain that?

Comment: Increasing gives injective, so if we compute the range of $g$, we have a bijective map between the domain of $g$ and the range of $g$.

Comment: And how does this yeld our desired result?

Comment: @mathlearner: He demonstrated the injectivity of $g(x)$ and hence proved there is a unique solution for $x = e$. Although, I agree that it does not directly show that $x(\ln x)^2 = e \implies x = e$. At best, this is a partial answer. Sorry, Jack.

Comment: @Nick I got that, but I don't understand how I prove that our unique solution is indeed $e$ (without making the obvious substitution).

Comment: There is no way, since the inverse function of $g$ is not a "nice" function, but depends on the Lambert W function: $$g^{-1}(x) = \exp\left(2 W(\sqrt{x}/2)\right). $$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Oh. I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $x = e$ checks out.

$f(x) = x(\ln(x))^2$ is strictly increasing so there is only at most one solution.

Comment: Conceptually here means without substituting $x=e$. Anyway, thank you for the remark on the monotonicity.

Comment: It is not strictly increasing in every domain, by looking at the plot one can see it is decreasing in the area around $\frac{1}{2}$ — in fact: $\frac{∂}{∂x}f=\left(\ln x\right)^2 + x\cdot 2\ln x \frac{1}{x} = 2\ln x + \left(\ln x\right)^2$. This gives you one extremum at $x=1$ and one at $x=e^{-2}$.

Comment: I think that's probably hopeless. I'm guessing that you probably have only a couple of ways to "know" that an answer is $e$ without plugging in:  (1) The $ln(x) = 1$, (2) x = \sum \frac{1}{n!}$. I don't see a reasonable way to transform your equation into either of these.  If there a reason that you think that "plugging in" is a bad thing?

Comment: @mathlearner, if an equation is proved to have a unique solution, why do you want to avoid computing the left side anywhere to see what its values are? Your equation has $e$ in it, on the right side, so avoiding computations with $e$ seems excessive.

Comment: @Lukas You're right, it is increasing from 1 onwards, and before that it's all below $y = e$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma indeed, but this still has to be proven and should not be stated as “trivial”, or did I miss something?

Comment: @Lukas Quite right, I was a bit too fast here. I was thinking only of $x \ge 1$, where everything is positive.